# Finding nearby addreses by geo location in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

I have stored users - including their addresses - and need to find all users who live within a certain distance of a specific location.

I am using `geocoder` and have stored longitude and latitude in the Users table.

How do I find these user?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Some examples would be nice to see where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Yes, if I get a user, then I can get the nearby users by calling user.nearbys([distance_in_miles]).
I have not found how to get those nearby to a location though (as opposed to nearby to user object).

Comment: Kindly paste your full code, including models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a query based on lat/lon, do this:

```
User.near([39.41, 90.23], 10)
```

That will find users within 10 miles of the lat/lon pair.

Here are the docs: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder